# JMenuItem Action Listener didn't wok properly

Tags: java, swing

so I want to open a new frame when the user presses jmenuitem, the actionlistener logOut manages to open a new frame, but the actionlistener for buyGames doesn't open a new frame, I've tried to change the class name of the frame but it still doesn't have any effect, here is my code created.
I hope someone can help me, thank you so much

```
public class Player extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
    JLabel stim = new JLabel("Stim");
    JPanel mai = new JPanel();
    JMenu acc, games;
    JMenuItem  logOut, ownedGames, buyGames;

    public Player(){
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        stim.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        stim.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC,40));
        //construct components
        menu.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        acc = new JMenu("Account");
        acc.setForeground(Color.white);
        games= new JMenu("Manage");
        games.setForeground(Color.white);

        logOut= new JMenuItem("Log Out");
        logOut.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        logOut.setForeground(Color.white);
        logOut.addActionListener(this);
        buyGames= new JMenuItem("Buy Games");
        buyGames.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        buyGames.setForeground(Color.white);
        ownedGames= new JMenuItem("Owned Genres");
        ownedGames.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        ownedGames.setForeground(Color.white);

        acc.add(logOut);
        games.add(buyGames);
        games.add(ownedGames);
        menu.add(acc);
        menu.add(games);

        stim.setBounds(190,120,110,110);

        //frame
        setTitle("Stim Database");
        setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(510, 400);
        setLayout(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setJMenuBar(menu);
        add(stim);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Player();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        if(e.getSource()==logOut) {
            LoginPage log = new LoginPage();
            this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
        }
        if(e.getSource()==buyGames) {
            BuyGames buy = new BuyGames();
            this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
        }
        if(e.getSource()==ownedGames) {
            //is not created yet
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HInt: add a printout to `actionPerformed` and see it runs

Comment: ah yeah mb i forgot to add it, thanks!

Comment: Well, there’s `logOut.addActionListener(this);` but no other `addActionListener` call. So it’s not surprising that only `logOut` does the expected thing. As a side note, when you use *different* action listeners, you don’t need the `if` ladder to find out what to do.